# i am not getting the device Registration id from the google and even not called GCMIntentService

Tags: android

i am not getting the device Registration id from the google and even not called GCMIntentService
  using the google i am create a server key..

below is my  manifest file
   but not getting the device register key from the google

```
package="com.example.isquare.pushexample" >

<receiver android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.example.isquare.pushexample" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".MyIntentService" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- GCM requires a Google account. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.example.isquare.pushexample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.isquare.pushexample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

    <!-- This app has permission to register and receive data message. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Network State Permissions to detect Internet status -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <!-- Permission to vibrate -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
```

Here is my GCMIntentService

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService {


    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    private Controller aController = null;

    public GCMIntentService() {
        // Call extended class Constructor GCMBaseIntentService

        super(Config.GOOGLE_SENDER_ID);
        System.out.println("the GCM ID IS ");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if(aController == null)
            aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

        Log.i(TAG, "Received message");
        String message = intent.getExtras().getString("price");

        aController.displayMessageOnScreen(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onError(Context context, String errorId) {
        if(aController == null)
            aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

        Log.i(TAG, "Received error: " + errorId);
        aController.displayMessageOnScreen(context,
                getString(R.string.gcm_error, errorId));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) {

        if(aController == null)
            aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

        Log.i(TAG, "Received deleted messages notification");
        String message = getString(R.string.gcm_deleted, total);
        aController.displayMessageOnScreen(context, message);
        // notifies user
        generateNotification(context, message);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean onRecoverableError(Context context, String errorId) {
        return super.onRecoverableError(context, errorId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        //Get Global Controller Class object (see application tag in AndroidManifest.xml)
        if(aController == null)
            aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();

        Log.i(TAG, "Device registered: regId = " + registrationId);
        aController.displayMessageOnScreen(context,
                "Your device registred with GCM");
        Log.d("NAME", MainActivity.name);
        aController.register(context, MainActivity.name,
                MainActivity.email, registrationId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) {
        if(aController == null)
            aController = (Controller) getApplicationContext();
        Log.i(TAG, "Device unregistered");
        aController.displayMessageOnScreen(context,
                getString(R.string.gcm_unregistered));
        aController.unregister(context, registrationId);
    }

    private static void generateNotification(Context context, String message) {

        int icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        // set intent so it does not start a new activity
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
        PendingIntent intent =
                PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
        notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

        // Play default notification sound
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

        //notification.sound = Uri.parse(
        "android.resource://"
                + context.getPackageName()
                + "your_sound_file_name.mp3");

        // Vibrate if vibrate is enabled
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notificationManager.notify(0, notification);

    }
```

Broadcast Receiver:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() { 
    @Override 
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(Config.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        aController.acquireWakeLock(getApplicationContext());  
        System.out.println(newMessage + ""); 
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Got Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
        aController.releaseWakeLock(); 
    } 
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() { 
@Override 
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) { 
    String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(Config.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
    aController.acquireWakeLock(getApplicationContext());  
    System.out.println(newMessage + ""); 
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Got Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); 
    aController.releaseWakeLock(); 
}
```

};

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where you are getting the Register Id.

```
if (mGoogleCloudMessaging == null) {
     mGoogleCloudMessaging = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(mContext);
}
regId = mGoogleCloudMessaging.register(C.google.SENDER_ID);
```

Here's a working example:
https://github.com/kweaver00/Android-Samples/tree/master/Push

After more information from comments:

Try adding replacing your `<receiver>` with the following:

```
<receiver android:name=".GCMBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
                <category android:name="YOUR_PACKAGE"/>
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Create a file `GCMBroadcastReceiver.java` with the following code:

```
public class GCMBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    public static final String TAG = "GCM_GCMBroadcastReceiver_";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
        Log.v(TAG, "OnReceive was called.");
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            MyIntentService.class.getName());
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);
            GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);
            final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);
            System.out.println("the reg is "+regId);
            if (regId.equals("")) {
                GCMRegistrar.register(this, Config.GOOGLE_SENDER_ID); // Note: get the sender id from configuration.
            } else {

                Log.v("Registration", "Already registered, regId: " + regId);
            }

Comment: And I'm assuming this printed a reg id?

Comment: in My Logcat i am getting this message                                          onReceive: com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION
10-22 19:35:35.236    1343-1343/com.example.pushexample V/GCMBroadcastReceiver﹕ GCM IntentService class: com.example.isquare.pushexample.GCMIntentService
10-22 19:35:35.236    1343-1343/com.example.pushexample V/GCMBaseIntentService﹕ Acquiring wakelock

Comment: I may know the solution but can you post your broadcast receiver too. Add it to your question and split the code between the manifest code and intent service (cleaner for the next guy)

Comment: private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {               String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(Config.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

            aController.acquireWakeLock(getApplicationContext());
            System.out.println(newMessage + "");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Got Message: " + newMessage,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            aController.releaseWakeLock();
        }
    };

Comment: edited my solution. If that works please up vote my solution. If not please provide logs.